# Fluent NHibernate - Cannot add items to a HasMany relationship with persisted data

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've got the following classes:

```
public class Client {
    public virtual Guid ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual string ClientName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ClientMonthlyRevenue> Revenue { get; set; }

    ...
    public virtual void SetMonthlyRevenue(int year, int month, double revenue)
    {   
        // Make sure it's not null... this might happen depending on how the client is created    
        if (Revenue == null)
        Revenue = new List<ClientMonthlyRevenue>();

        // Check for existance - we don't want any duplicates        
        ClientMonthlyRevenue clientMonthlyRevenue = Revenue.Where(x => x.Year == year && x.Month == month).FirstOrDefault();        
        if (clientMonthlyRevenue == null)        
        {
            // If it doesn't exist, create a new one and add to the list
            clientMonthlyRevenue = new ClientMonthlyRevenue(this, year, month, revenue);
            this.Revenue.Add(clientMonthlyRevenue);   // This is the line throwing the error
        }
        else
        {
            // If it exists, just update it
            clientMonthlyRevenue.Revenue = revenue;
        }
    }
}

public class ClientMonthlyRevenue {
    public virtual Client ParentClient { get; set; }
    public virtual int Year { get; set; }
    public virtual int Month { get; set; }
    public virtual double Revenue { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And these two mappings:

```
public class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
{
    Id(x => x.ClientID).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    Map(x => x.ClientName);

    HasMany<ClientMonthlyRevenue>(x => x.Revenue)
        .Table("ClientMonthlyRevenue")
        .KeyColumn("ClientID")
        .Cascade.All()
        .Fetch.Join();
}

public class ClientMonthlyRevenueMap : ClassMap<ClientMonthlyRevenue>
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyReference(x => x.Client, "ClientID")
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Year)
        .KeyProperty(x => x.Month);

    Map(x => x.Revenue);
}
```

When I get a Client from the database:

```
Client client = Session.Get<Client>(clientID);
```

all the data is there, which is great. But when I try to add a new ClientMonthlyRevenue child:

```
client.Revenue.Add(new ClientMonthlyRevenue(this.ClientID, year, month, revenue));
```

I get the error:

```
Collection was of a fixed size.
```

Am I missing or misunderstanding something here? And what do I need to modify to be able to add items to this persisted list?

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace? I was able to create this as a sample and it worked fine for me?

Comment: The stacktrace is pretty uninteresting... it points to the indicated line in the Client class (I added the function throwing the error), below that is just my program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the Client object to have the following:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        Revenue = new List<ClientMonthlyRevenue>();
    }

    public virtual Guid ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual string ClientName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ClientMonthlyRevenue> Revenue { get; set; }

    public virtual void AddRevenue(ClientMonthlyRevenue revenue)
    {
        revenue.ParentClient = this;
        Revenue.Add(revenue);
    }
}
```

Then you can call like this:

```
public void TestMapping()
{
    session.BeginTransaction();
    var client = new Client{ClientID = Guid.NewGuid()};
    session.SaveOrUpdate(client);

    client = session.Get<Client>(client.ClientID);
    client.AddRevenue(new ClientMonthlyRevenue(2001,07,1200));
    session.Transaction.Commit();
}
```

The error you are receiving sounds like it could be created higher up in the stack.  I was able to recreate your scenario. See full source: https://gist.github.com/1098337

Comment: You are correct. After some digging, I figured out this was being caused by some voodoo framework code that automagically serializes objects inherited off a couple classes - when the list got serialized, it converted it to a static sized array.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to mark your collection as Inverse? I dont know if it could help.

```
HasMany<ClientMonthlyRevenue>(x => x.Revenue)
    .Table("ClientMonthlyRevenue")
    .KeyColumn("ClientID")
    .Cascade.All()
    .Fetch.Join()
    .Inverse();
```

Comment: I want Client to control the ClientMonthlyRevenue object so that I never need to explicitly save the child object.

Comment: Adding Inverse() just changes which mapping controls the save. By calling Cascade.All() your clientmap is still instigating the save, but deferring the save operation to the revenuemap. This makes a difference in the sql generated. Without inverse, you will see a bunch of DELETE operations, then INSERT operations. With inverse, you will see the one INSERT operation.

Comment: Wow, I totally misunderstood what Inverse() was for.. Thanks! Sadly, it did not help the problem.